# Why can't I use properties from my ObservableCollection inside a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to return an `Observablecollection`, what seems to be fine. When I want to get the properties of each item in the collection, I get the error "Binding: Property '' not found on".

I have the following code:
*I removed all markup code, to make it easier to  read*

**View**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Date}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class BookListPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Book> _books = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
    {
        get => _books;
        set => SetProperty(ref _books, value);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Book : ModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

The weird thing is, earlier I had the class `Book` inside the `ViewModel` file and that did work. But I want this class to be in the `Models` folder.
This is how my `ViewModel` looked like before.

```
namespace Some.Namespace.Project
{
    public class Book : ModelBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class BooksListPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Book> _books = new();
        public ObservableCollection<Book> Books
        {
            get => _books;
            set => SetProperty(ref _books, value);
        }
    }
}
```

How is it that the `Bindings (Title, Description, and Date)` are not found?

Comment: Sort of wild guessing here, but the fact that you're using `List` as the name of the property bound to the ItemSource could be throwing things off (there is a `System.Collections.Generic.List`). Can you try renaming is to something more specific like `ListOfParts`?

Comment: Ah, ye. Maybe not the best alternative for here, but that's not really the variable name in my code. I'm not allowed to share any code. I edited the variable names :)

Comment: Why are `private ObservableCollection<Book> _books` and `public ObservableCollection<Parts> Books` different types? That looks weird but maybe it's just a typo. Also I presume the `SetProperty` raises a property changed event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to XAML and apparently it's possible to add your own `x-tags` in the `ContentPage`.

So in my ContentPage I added `xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Namespace.To.Models"`.
With this tag I can change my `DataTemplate` to `<DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Book">`.

This solved the problem for me.